SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:2559) error while transcribing audio files from an API using whisper-turbo model
I am converting some audio calls coming from an Api using OpenAI whispers latest large-turbo model. During conversion at some point, it gives this error ([SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:2559)) which I am unable to understand. What is this error and how can I fix this?
I am doing this:
import whisper

turbo  = whisper.load_model("turbo")

while True:
    for url in links_from_api():
        result = turbo.transcribe(url)
        data = result["text"]
        print(data)

But it is not running continuously, at some point it is giving the mentioned error. I am expecting this to run continuously without getting stopped.

This question is similar to: Why am I getting "OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_read: sslv3 alert bad record mac" intermittently from Heroku Redis?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
